# datatable column filter not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I have the column filter js on my page along with my datatable and everything is coming up and working no errors in the console, but the inputs at the bottom are not there after the smoothness loads.

```
<body>
    <div id="stable" style=" margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; display: none">
        <table class="display" id="table_id">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>Call Date</th>
                     <th>Unique ID</th>
                     <th>Source</th>
                     <th>App</th>
                     <th>Destination</th>
                     <th>Disposition</th>
                     <th>Duration</th>          
                 </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <th>Call Date</th>
                    <th>Unique ID</th>
                    <th>Source</th>
                    <th>App</th>
                    <th>Destination</th>
                    <th>Disposition</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>    
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody></tbody>            
        </table>
    </div>           
</body>

$('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": selected });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "15%", "mData": "calldate" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sClass": "system", "sType": "string", "sWidth": "15%", "mData": "uniqueid" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "mData": "clid" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "mData": "lastapp" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "mData": "dst" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "mData": "disposition" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", "sType": "string", "mData": "duration_in_mins_and_secs" }, ],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Export",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }]
        }
    }).columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [ 
                { type: "select", values: [ 'Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']  },
                { type: "text" },
                 null,
                { type: "number" },
                { type: "select", values: [ 'A', 'C', 'U', 'X']  },
                null,
                null,
                null
        ]

    });
```

Like i said it applies then is gone once the table fully initializes.

On my main page

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/layout.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/userdblist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/jquerymask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/columnFilter.js"></script>
```

I have the table php included into my main page with these

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
```

I am also wanting the inputs to be at the top but that is another issue ill work on. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why the column filters don't show at all.  Perhaps because you defined 8 of them, but the rest of your table has 7 columns?

To get the column filter inputs to the top, you need to move your second group of column headers from the `tfoot` section to the `thead` section:

```
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Call Date</th>
                 <th>Unique ID</th>
                 <th>Source</th>
                 <th>App</th>
                 <th>Destination</th>
                 <th>Disposition</th>
                 <th>Duration</th>          
             </tr> 
             <tr>
                <th>Call Date</th>
                <th>Unique ID</th>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>App</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Disposition</th>
                <th>Duration</th>    
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>....
```

You also need to add sPlaceHolder as you set up columnFilter:

```
}).columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
    aoColumns: [ ...
```

Not sure what the capital `T` in your sDom represents.  Do you want `l` or `f`?

Comment: I added the tips you provided and the T is for tabletools, but still no input. I can see it for half a second but then disappears.

Comment: Yeah, it's something when the javascript runs that hides it.  Try taking out the sDom and see if that's causing the problem.  Try to narrow it down by eliminating one feature at a time.

Comment: I am having no luck modifying the sdom and or completely removing it. Nothing I do can get it to show up and not go away.

Comment: I guess my strategy would be to strip out all the options at the top of the dataTable so that you have something that works, even if it's missing critical features.  Then start adding them back in one by one so you can isolate the conflict.

Comment: I see you found why the col filters didn't show up.  Did you get them moved to the top?

Comment: I did, the only odd problem I am having now is the row in the thead that the column filters use has a transparent background as in its like the table just broke put the filters in then continued.

Answer (score 1):

It does not show up with "sScrollY" enabled on the datatable.